# where is my ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, live-usb, bootloader

i have 4 partitions.

---

1 system part of windows.
2 windows installed(7 x64).
3 i common drive for temp files.

### 4 my drive for my personal data.

i downloaded ubuntu 12.10 x64
shrinked my windows drive about 10gb.
burned ubuntu iso in pendrive by linux iso burner.
booted in the pendrive,
selected TRY UBUNTU,
selected install ubuntu
there then i seleced -SOME THING ELSE for --(how u want to install ubuntu) 
i selected the drive -- add -- ext4 -- install.....
then it said reboot..
i did so...
and after restart as pendrive is in it always get into the screen where the options says
try ubuntu.
install ubuntu.
and 2 more options.
so that time i remove the pd and restart the system.
but when ever the system boots.. it boots directly into windows.
inside windows 
i went to --- run --- msconfig --- boot selection--
there is only windows...
no ubuntu detected...

so where is my ubuntu..
its disappeared after proper installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is, when you selected to add a new ext4 partition, have you set mount point as **`/`**. Other wise you will get error about `root system`.

Secondly, choose `booloader location` as your hard disk (probably `sda`) not your usb (`sdb`). This options is located in the same screen where partition are shown (just after `something else`)

If it fails again after installation,boot with live disk (Try ubuntu) & use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: the bootloader is set to sda only because i remember in the end it was (1.0 tb) thats the size of my hdd
and yes the mount part i have set to root .. still error...
now what should i do? 
hmm again do "Try Ubuntu"-- and inside try ubuntu -- run boot-repair??
i can only work on windows 7 thats the only os in my laptop for now other than ubuntu which does not at all show up.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you did was select a partition for your bootloader that was not the active partition or the mbr. Since we can not be sure exactly what you did we'll just do it again. Boot to your usb drive and install Ubuntu. Be careful to set Grub (the bootloader) to the drive (probably sda) do not set it to sda1, sda2 or anything with a number. It sounds like you only have one hard drive on this computer. That's good. If you happen to have two or more drives be sure you install your bootloader to the drive you boot from, or you'll have to change the bios to reflect your new boot-drive.  Remember you can reinstall as often as you like. If you mess up once (and who hasn't?) just start over.

Comment: the bootloader is set to sda only because i remember in the end it was (1.0 tb) thats the size of my hdd
and yes the mount part i have set to root .. still error... now what should i do? hmm again do "Try Ubuntu"-- and inside try ubuntu -- run boot-repair?? i can only work on windows 7 thats the only os in my laptop for now other than ubuntu which does not at all show up.